# Sum if cells contain specific text and subtotal

Tags: excel

## Updated:

I've excel 2007 spreadsheet which is look like this
[image: excel sheet]
I did all header to filter, So in `C` column there could be lot of fodder type. I want when i filtered only `Corn` or `Nipiar` then show all total quantity only for visible rows.

I tried this code but it return all corn or nipiar quantity but i need only visible rows

For Corn:

```
=SUMIF(C6:C500,"corn",D6:D500)
```

For Nipiar:

```
=SUMIF(C6:C500,"nipiar",D6:D500)
```

I tried also , it did not work cause i need depend on specific text like corn or nipiar or whatever

```
=SUBTOTAL(9,D6:D500)
```

Comment: I'm not an Excel expert, but this sounds like a problem which pivot tables would be well suited to handle.  Have you heard of pivot tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to deal with the hidden/visible property of the quantities in column D individually. Use [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) for this style of cyclic processing and [OFFSET](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-b3958b36-c30b-4fc3-979e-9b9bbfdcf592) with [ROW](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) to break the D6:D500 range into individual values to be preprocessed by the [SUBTOTAL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af) into invalid hidden values and valid visible ones.

Before filtering:

[image: Sumproduct_Subtotal_unfiltered]

After filtering column G for *Sheep*:

[image: Sumproduct_Subtotal_filtered]

Comment: Your Code not working

You see my picture? I can filter anything like `date` , `source name`, `fodder description`, `code` 
After all filtered then showing corn = ? or nipiar = ?

Comment: My code working. See images above.

Comment: Why you use `ROW($1:$8)` ?
I use this code , try all filtering but showing zero
`=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET($D$6,ROW($6:$500)-1, 0, 1, 1)), --($C$6:$C$500=I5))`

Comment: @TawhidulIslam If you are not going to start with row 1 on the counter then you need subtract 6 not 1.

Answer (score 1):

Since once filtered for `Corn` I think you want to add all visible, please try:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,D:D)
```

Comment: please again look at question, it's updated