# Excel PivotTable "Show Values As % of item" not correctly calculated

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, excel-2013, powerpivot

I am having trouble using the "Show value as"-functionality in my pivottable in Excel 2013. My pivot should look like the table below:

However, when I calculate "Show value as % of "1. Turnover", only the row headers (being Turnover, General costs and variable costs) are correctly calculated. **The % of turnover for the items 70XXX, 61XXX, 60XXX) display "NA"**. Can anyone help me to explain how I should apply this functionality?

Thanks!

Jasper

[image]

Comment: I am not really sure what is going on in your table. How can 15 be 100% and 10 75%? Or 1 be 20% and 2 only 13%

Comment: Apologies, something went wrong in my example. I updated the image. For every location, I would like to see the percentage based on his turnover. For example for item 70XXXX with value 10 this will lead to 10/15=66,67%.

Comment: Can you add extra column that would do % calculation for you?

Comment: I've updated the picture!

Comment: Sorry, I meant add extra column to your data table. I don't think that "Show value as" functionality can solve your problem. I think it will be easier to workout the percentages in an extra column and just output them to your pivot.

Comment: Done! Yeah, I thought about this option as well but the user can use a slicer to specify the date range (-> the turnover could change frequently) and thus the query should be reloaded every time they change the filter. For the moment I am experimenting with calculated fields..

Comment: There is very similar problem

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38579644/sum-if-cells-contain-specific-text-and-subtotal]

Comment: Thanks for your collaboration @Aneta. I managed to solve this issue on my own.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by creating a calculated field.

`DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[value]);CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[value]);'Table'[header]="1. Turnover";ALL('Table'[header];'Table'[subheader])))`